# What is the number in the name of a device tree device?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I'm using the device tree to register a built-in keypad for an embedded Linux device.

The keypad is registered as `matrix-keypad.69`. I know `matrix-keypad` is the name of device as specified in the dts file. But what does `69` mean?

How is this number determined?

Is it deterministic? Can I make it deterministic?

Comment: This is an ID of the instance of certain driver. It may be deterministic, depending how the driver handles it. Yes, you can make this number known beforehand. (Note, in device tree enabled platforms usually this number doesn't matter for anything to work)

Comment: @0andriy I think the number is determined by the generic code for loading device tree drivers in the kernel, not by the code of any specific driver (looking at the code of the matrix-keypad driver, for example, it doesn't seem to add a number to its name). I'm trying to find where in the kernel this number is determined, and how to make it deterministic.